# Windows 10 no Wi-Fi networks found

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I normally use ethernet so I'm not sure when this happened, but I can't see any Wi-Fi connections on my PC. I can see plenty on other devices (phone, tablet etc.). I'm using a tether on my phone to post this, so the service is fine, something is up with the PC.

At first I couldn't even see a Wi-Fi option in the notification area. After a Google session I checked the WLAN AutoConfig service was set to start automatically. It was NOT. After setting this to auto and restarting this I was able to see Wi-Fi in the notification area unlike before and can see the 'no available Wi-Fi networks message there'.

Things I have tried:

- A USB Wi-Fi adapter that is working in on my laptop.
- Updating drivers.
- Checking the Wi-Fi connection uses the right items (QoS packet scheduler, Link-Layer,
  Topology Discovery Responder, Internet Protocol Version 4 & 6,
  Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper I/O driver, Microsoft LLDP
  Protocol Driver, Client for Microsoft Networks).
- Adding DhcpConnEnableBcastFlagToggle flag in RegEdit
- Running the network troubleshooter in Settings; it reports "Investigate router or access point issues: Failed" and advises to check if the router is switched on
- Network reset, both via Windows Settings and the usual command prompt calls.
- Windows repair using boot media, opting the keep files and installed apps.

Comment: What does Device Manager say about the Wireless card? Also see if you can run Hardware diagnostics on the card

Comment: @John Device status says 'This device is working properly.'. Driver check says it's the latest version. In connection manager the connection shows a red X and 'Not connected'. I should mention it's integrated into the mobo but I got the same with the USB adaptor too.

Comment: I am not sure as the USB adapter does the same thing and it has its own antenna

Comment: If you reinstalled Windows, then it sounds like you have suffered an hardware failure, with regards to any built-in WiFIi adapters.  If the USB WiFi adapter does not work, without knowing more about the adapter or the access point, your question is very difficult to answer as you have provided virtually no diagnostic information.

Comment: @Ramhound It's unlikely a hardware issue as the same happens with the USB adaptor. What diagnostic info do you require?

Comment: @Absinthe - If your trying to use a 2.4 GHz WiFi standard, and are expecting 5.0 GHz networks, that will never work.  You seem like you were expecting for your hardware to have a built-in WiFi adapter but the fact you had to take manual intervention to start services that might not be the case.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not expecting 5GHz and the mobo definately has wifi built in. As mentioned all other devices are reading the signal OK (as well as other signals in the area). Please clarify what more 'diagnostic info' you need before voting to close the question. I feel the question is of good quality and you did not state what you want. Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Information about the adapter and the access point that isn't being listed.  Specific detailed hardware information.  Windows build information. The only time in 20+ years I have ever seen Windows NOT display the icon to connect to a wireless network is when the wireless adapter didn't exist.  The only time in all those years a network wasn't listed is due to a compatibility mixed match. Based on your comment, which does not exist in your question, it appears you are connecting the network you want, but the network being detected as "not being connected to the internet". I won't be returning.

Comment: Your local network setup is unclear: Seems like you're tethering on your phone, but how are both connected. And the wifi is being broadcast by which device?

Comment: @Absinthe, try a simple test: 1. Make a Linux live USB, e.g., https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/ . 2. Boot from the USB -- no need to install *anything* on the PC's drive. 3. Try WiFi -- if it works, then it's a Windows OS issue. If not, then most likely it's a hardware issue. (BTW, one PC I have has a physical toggle switch to turn WiFi on or off.)

Answer (score -1):

Stumbled across the problem; the mobo (Asus TUF Z790 PLUS) actually requires a wifi aerial that's supplied with it to be plugged in for wifi to work!